# what's intuition of $\sigma(X_1, X_2,...)$ in asymptotic analysis?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

In asymptotic analysis, we consider countable many random variables $X_1, X_2,...$ and $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$ means the smallest sigma field containing the information of $X_1, X_2,...$.

So my question is that, since $\sigma(X_1)\subset\sigma(X_1,X_2)\subset...\subset\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$.

Does it means that $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$ is a infinity large sigma field, and when we consider $X_1,X_2,...$ we have infinity "information"?

If not, at which point does this increasing sigma field converge? Or when does this increasing sigma field stop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$ is indeed infinitely large.  It contains all of the information obtained by observing the whole $X_1,X_2,...$ sequence, so it doesn't in general "stop" and there's no set point where it "converges."  The exception would be if the later $X_n$ are eventually all functions of earlier $X_n$; then they don't add any new information.  For example, if $X_n = (X_1)^n$ for $n > 1$, then $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...) = \sigma(X_1)$.

Comment: Thank you! it's really helpful, Just for clarify, if we have $iid$ random variables $X_1, X_2,....$, then it means we have  $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)=\sigma(X_1)$, and if we only have independent $X_1,X_2,...$ then $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$ is a infinitely large sigma field. Am i correct?

Comment: No, if the random variables are iid then $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...) \ne \sigma(X_1)$.  Even though they are identically distributed, knowing $X_1$ doesn't give you any information about $X_2$ so the $\sigma$-algebras are not the same.  The only way you could have $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...) = \sigma(X_1)$ is if $X_1$ tells you exactly what all of the other $X_i$ are.  In almost all circumstances, $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...) \ne \sigma(X_1)$.

Comment: So it means that as long as we have independent $X_1, X_2,...$, then $\sigma(X_1, X_2,...)$ is infinitely large right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.